# Does $n\pi - \lfloor n\pi\rfloor$ have a subsequence that goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $n\pi - \lfloor n\pi\rfloor$ have a subsequence that goes to zero? I was talking to a friend about it but neither of us were able to come up with anything. We're not sure if $\pi$ is essential here or if any irrational could be used instead, but we noticed that every term in the sequence is between $0$ and $1$, so it has a convergent subsequence.

Help?

Comment: given any irrational number $q,$ the integer multiples are dense $\pmod 1.$ See, for example, Niven, Diophantine Approximation  http://store.doverpublications.com/0486462676.html

Comment: Even more, for any irrational $q$, the sequence $nq\bmod1$ is uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $n$ to be the denominators of alternate continued fraction approximations to $\pi$ (i.e. alternate terms of [OEIS A002486](http://oeis.org/A002486)): $1,106,33102,66317,265381,1360120, \ldots$ and you get approximately $0.1415927,  0.0088213,  0.0000191,  0.0000081,  0.0000023,  0.0000005,\ldots$

Comment: Jinx. :) ${}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes - you beat me by a few seconds

Answer (score 4):

A constructive approach would be to take the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$ and then consider the even convergents. Then $$0<\pi-\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}<\frac 1{q_{2n}^2}$$

and $q_{2n}\to\infty$.

Comment: What is an even convergent ?